# I tried using postgresql on laravel but got could not find driver (SQL: select * from "users" where "id" = 4 limit 1)

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, postgresql

Good day fellow Artisans, please I have an issue with PostgreSql, I have an application that I am using MySql and everything is working fine, but I have to use another database PostgresSql, I did the necessary connection and ran **php artisan migrate**, the migration ran without errors and the tables were created, but when I try to register a new user, I got this error.

I have cleared my cache, route, config, and also view

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

[image: Postgres error]

**.env**

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=mydatabase
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=mypassword
```

I am using **WAMP**, so I have uncommented the pgsql extension in **php.ini**

```
;extension=pdo_odbc
extension=pdo_pgsql
extension=pdo_sqlite
extension=pgsql
;extension=phpdbg_webhelper
```

running **php -m**, it listed **pdo_pgsql** also

Comment: When you use `php -m | grep pgsql`, what is output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you all for your contributions, but I guess my system was the cause because it seems I did everything right initially, what happened was, After I got that error and I was not able to resolve it then, I switched back to MySql and continued with my task, at the end, I needed to restart my system for system update, after restarting, I said I should give the PostgreSql a shot, I edited my .env back to the configuration above, and also run **php artisan config:cache**, (which I did before) and the error is gone, I am now using PostgreSql with my laravel application.

**My Observations**

1. I need to restart my system after I uncomment **pgsql** and **pdo_pgsql** in my **php.ini**.
2. I must stop my **WAMPSERVER** and also my **php artisan serve** was running, I should have stopped and restarted them.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you enable lack of extension. We also need to enable `php_pgsql` and  `php_pdo_pgsql` in `php.ini` because your PHP installation does not support PostgreSQL.

After enabling this extensions, you may not see installed extension in `phpinfo`. In this case, you should check error log; you may need to install additional libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Removing comments on php_pgsql and php_pdo_pgsql extensions in php.ini file, restarting artisan serve solved the problem for me.